# Pattern matching and get multiple values from URL using java

Tags: java, regex, apache-commons

I am using Java-8, I would like to check whether the URL is valid or not based on pattern.
If valid then I should get the attributes bookId, authorId, category, mediaId

```
Pattern: <basepath>/books/<bookId>/author/<authorId>/<isbn>/<category>/mediaId/<filename>
```

And this is the sample URL

```
URL => https:/<baseurl>/v1/files/library/books/1234-4567/author/56784589/32475622347586/media/324785643257567/507f1f77bcf86cd799439011_400.png
```

Here Basepath is /v1/files/library.

I see some pattern matchings but I couldn't relate with my use-case, probably I was not good at reg-ex. I am also using apache-common-utils but I am not sure How to achieve it either.

Any help or hint would be really appreciable.

Comment: What regex have you tried, or are you just hoping we'll write your code for you?

Comment: @Andreas I have used subStringBetween and subStringAfter in regEx to get values from url but i don’t know how to write patterns to check whether it is valid or not. I’m trying myself in parallel. Will edit my question and post my update if I get closer

Comment: What does *"subStringBetween and subStringAfter in regEx"* mean? Show the regex you've tried.

Comment: I’m getting entire url in string...so used commons stringUtils to get the values between urls in strings since few attributes are fixed in the url like book,author etc

Comment: *"I’m getting entire url"* (singular) then *"values between urls"* (plural). What does that mean? Do you have 1 or many URLs? And what does that have to do with regex?

Comment: @Andreas The solution shared by Ogod works. It's a single URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution (uses named capture groups in regex):

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http[s]?:.+/books/(?<bookId>[^/]+)/author/(?<authorId>[^/]+)/(?<isbn>[^/]+)/media/(?<mediaId>[^/]+)/(?<filename>.+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("https:/<baseurl>/v1/files/library/books/1234-4567/author/56784589/32475622347586/media/324785643257567/507f1f77bcf86cd799439011_400.png");
        if (m.matches())
        {
            System.out.println("bookId = " + m.group("bookId"));
            System.out.println("authorId = " + m.group("authorId"));
            System.out.println("isbn = " + m.group("isbn"));
            System.out.println("mediaId = " + m.group("mediaId"));
            System.out.println("filename = " + m.group("filename"));
        }
    }
```

prints:

```
bookId = 1234-4567
authorId = 56784589
isbn = 32475622347586
mediaId = 324785643257567
filename = 507f1f77bcf86cd799439011_400.png
```

Comment: Add the `[^/]+` should be `[^/?#]+`, since a `?` or a `#` would terminate the *path*-part of the URL.